# Is it possible to replace $_POST with $_FILES 

Tags: php

Excuse me if my english is not grammatical....

**Is it possible to replace $_POST with $_FILES ?**

In my program, i copied all information of a register form to an array

Like This

```
$this->RegistrationFields['profile_img'] = array( 'name' => 'Image','type' => 'BLOB', 'table' => 'users', 'field' => 'profile_img');
```

and get values using foreach

```
foreach( $this->RegistrationFields as $fields => $values )
```

after that it check for field is set or not

```
if( ! isset( $_POST['register_' . $fields] ) || $_POST['register_' . $fields] == '' )
        {
            $this->submittedValues[ $fields ] = $_POST['register_' . $fields];
            $this->errorLabels['register_' . $fields] = 'error';
            $this->errors[] = 'Field ' . $data['name'] . ' cannot be empty';
        }
```

But the problem is that it always shows error message when uploading images,

I guess i have to replace the $_POST with $_FILES ***while checking image***,

SO i put

```
if ($fields == 'profile_img')
{
    //replace $_POST with $_FILES   
}
```

just above the **ISSET** condition

**So my question is :**

**Is there an inbuld function to replace $_POST with $_FILES???? in **PHP****

**EDIT : Or else i could use str_replace?**

Comment: Why do you look in a wrong *array* then?

Comment: `to replace php tag`. Wait, what?

Comment: @JamWaffles : I mean $_POST with $_FILES???

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: Superglobals are not read-only so you can do almost everything you want with them. Of course, changing their default meaning can do no good to your code base.

Comment: @Alvaro : 

I have to check image file isset using $_FILES when the fields value becomes "profile_img"??? Is there an alternate way???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` holds data coming from the HTTP POST request to the page.

`$_FILES` holds all data pertaining to a file that's been uploaded.

You can't swap the two over. If you want to see if a file has been uploaded, try using

```
isset($_FILES['name'])
```

Or (better still):

```
if(!$_FILES['error'])
```

Which will see if there's been an error uploading the file anywhere.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to check the $_FILES is set or not??

Comment: You can see if any element inside `$_FILES` is set. Have tried `isset($_FILES['name'])`, given above? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: In my code,the if condtion checks all fields in the array has been set or not using $_POST variable,but i guess that's not applicable for image files

Ie: image files is checked using $_FILES.isn't it?